# AutoHotKey AHK to stop and exit script and time variable

Tags: autohotkey

I've a simple script to press a function key after a preset time.  eg: 1min (60,000 milliseconds)

1. The issue is I want it to stop after it's run the function key and completely exit the app automatically.

I can find heaps of advice to assign a hotkey, but this is of no use as I'II be wanting this to perform the stop and exit function un-attended.

2. Also is there a way for a popup window to appear to enter the time variable for the function key to run....rather than specifically creating an AHK file with the time hardcoded for each different time I need it to run?...perhaps only accept with a min value of 1min (60,000).
3. If not, had an idea to use an xls VBA countdown timer
   https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/timer-stopwatch-excel-vba#dl_anchor to open the AHKrunFunctionKey.exe file to run the function key.

   #Persistent
   SetTimer, PressTheKey, 60000
   Return

   PressTheKey:
   Send, {F12}
   Return

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean. I guess you either want to run the timer only once (which can be done with a negative time) or you want to put an ExitApp instruction in your subroutine.

Comment: tkx SCSO.  The negative time works great to only run it once.  I've looked at posts for how to exit the app/script and are unable to find any that exit without the need to press a hot key.  Would you know what exit statement I'd need to write?

Comment: [`ExitApp`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ExitApp.htm)

Comment: Tkx Spyre,  Used the below from your next response and works fine.
ExitApp
Return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have all of the features you requested:

- Variable input GUI

  - Achieved with [`InputBox`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm)
- Exits program on completion

  - Achieved with [`ExitApp`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ExitApp.htm)

Code:

```
#Persistent
InputBox, UserInput, Delay Box, Please enter the amount of time to delay
if ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, Aborted
else
    SetTimer, PressTheKey, -%UserInput%
Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {F12}
MsgBox Completed
ExitApp
Return
```

Feel free to lmk if you want anything changed or added

Comment: When running this, the message box appears, but the app doesn't run.  Looking in the task manager, it definitely isn't running in the background.

Comment: When launching the exe, it appears in the 'Apps" of the task manager, but after entering in the time (60,000), it closes down.  Tried a mod by removing the "MsgBox Completed" and I get a flash of the app in the background processes before it closes down without doing the function key.

Comment: @Bart101 you need to put `#Persistent` as the first line of the script to fix that issue. I recommend you to read here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Persistent.htm

Comment: Sorry about that @Bart101! As @scso mentioned, you would also need to include `#Persistent` at the top of the program. I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks Spyre & Scso for your help.  It now does exactly what I needed.  Looking at some further posts, can't believe what's possible which AHK